# I need to know how to do more with the mechanics of the <datalist tag>

Tags: html

I am writing a code for registering 'characters' on my website. Note: Characters are different from users. I am using a  tag to put options for them when they register a new character. Here is my coding (A small bit of it.)

```
 <p> Is the character fictional or non-fictional? </p> <input list="fiction" name="fiction"> <datalist id="fiction">
<option value="Fictional">
<option value="Non-fictional">
```

Okay, let's say I wanted the users to fill in different details depending on what choice they picked on the entrance above.
For example, if they picked fictional, I could ask "In what piece of fiction is this character in?" And if they picked non-fictional, "What job does this person do?"

Please help me, I've only started covering coding in less than six months, and I have been busy with school. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look like some assignment for SO

Answer (score 0):

So the datalist tag provides preconfigured options for an input field. If i understood that correct than, after a user selected one of both, you want to ask him further questions about the character. 
Why dont you do this via a javascript function ?
you could listen to a change on the inputfield and then get the selected value with `document.getElementById('textbox_id').value` , distinguish between the input possibilities and then show the proper response for it.